# Discord.js-button : DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

I am currently coding a bot discord.
I have an error about the buttons. The question has already been asked on the forum, but I haven't found a relevant answer...
When running the first command, everything works fine, when running the second command, this message appears...

**==> Here is the code:**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

    const row = new MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('yes')
                .setLabel('YES')
                .setStyle('SUCCESS'),
            
            new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('no')
                .setLabel('NO')
                .setStyle('DANGER'),
        );

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle('Some title')
            
    await message.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] });

    client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
        if (interaction.customId == 'yes') {
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'You click on YES !', ephemeral: true });
        };
    });

};

module.exports.info = {
    names: ['t4', 'test4'],
};
```

**==> Here is the error:**

```js
throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\famou\OneDrive\Bureau\RPG Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:298:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\famou\OneDrive\Bureau\RPG Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async ButtonInteraction.reply (C:\Users\famou\OneDrive\Bureau\RPG Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:99:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\famou\OneDrive\Bureau\RPG Bot\commands\test4.js:45:13) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/interactions/997619679268970577/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246OTk3NjE5Njc5MjY4OTcwNTc3OjJsZmhuWlJWaVJYNnJlcnhJNkFtSXhhcEllM2Vhd0VQdVJOYTQwdzF0Y3IyakpGWVh1Vkd1a3BXeHZyc25aTFFOYk9uMVQ2QkNFTGJPQmFaVjdvWG90eTB3V1I3ckR3ZFd3TGd3YjdGejREajBZeGhKUWtRc3F3c3BMdlR2QW1a/callback',
  code: 40060,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
        content: 'Ready! You closed the channel!',
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        embeds: undefined,
        components: undefined,
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
        flags: 64,
        message_reference: undefined,
        attachments: undefined,
        sticker_ids: undefined
      }
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating nested listeners. You are creating a listener whenever the command is run, doing no validation at all in the callback, making it take *every* interaction, even from a different command. A better option is to use [collectors](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#collectors).

```js
const msg = await message.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] });
const collector = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({
  componentType: "BUTTON",
  time: 15_000 // how long you want it to collect for, in ms (this is 15 seconds)
})

collector.on('collect', async interaction => {
  if (interaction.customId == 'yes') {
    await interaction.reply({ content: 'You click on YES !', ephemeral: true });
  };
});
```

Docs: [`Message#createMessageComponentCollector()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createMessageComponentCollector)